# File input for select statement in shell scipt

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I have a text file which has inputs for select statement.

```
sqlplus -s $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$HOST<< EOF
spool $DIRECTORY/UPDATE.xls
select acc,cr,dr from count where acc in $DIRECTORY/acc.txt;
spool off;
exit
EOF
```

Please let me know how to use the text file as input at highlighted part.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the back tics for that in combination with the `cat` command. So

```
select acc,cr,dr from count where acc in `cat $DIRECTORY/acc.txt`;
```